# Yii passing value from one controller to another

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework for my application. My application contain 4 controllers in which I want to pass value from one controller to another.

Let us consider site and admin controller. In site controller, I manage the login validation and retrieves admin id from database. But I want to send admin id to admin controller.

I try session variable, its scope only within that controller.

Please suggest the possible solution for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please go through some basic tutorial & google search ...

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a redirect:

In the `siteController` file

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    //Perform your operation
    //The next line will redirect the user to 
    //the AdminController in the action called loggedAction
    $this->redirect(array('admin/logged', array(
        'id' => $admin->id,
        'param2' => $value2
    )));
}
```

in the `adminController` file

```
public function loggedAction($id, $param2)
{
    //you are in the other action and params are set
}
```

Comment: Ya I retrieve only by using $_GET['id']. Can you some suggestion by getting value using $_POST[]

Comment: You can't with POST. If you don't want to set GET values, then you could consider using session